# Checkstyle issuing an indentation warning on an annotation?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have an annotation like:

```
@ComponentScan(
  basePackages = {
    "com.example.foo",
    "com.example.bar"
  }   // <--- false positive reported in this line
)
public class FooBar extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
}
```

And a Checkstyle configuration of:

```
<module name="AnnotationUseStyle" />
<module name="Indentation">
  <property name="basicOffset" value="2" />
  <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0" />
  <property name="caseIndent" value="2" />
</module>
```

When I run my project through Checkstyle, I get an error stating "assign child at indentation level 2 not at correct indentation, 4". This is referencing line 5 of my code example above, i.e. the closing parenthetical for the `basePackages` property.

What configuration change to Checkstyle would I need to make for this annotation to validate correctly?

Comment: This appears to be a limitation of the Indentation check. The check seems to think you are on another column. In the CheckStyle 5.6 sources, I could not find anything that handles annotations specifically. Maybe it's just not implemented at the moment.

Comment: You know, it could be the `()`. My actual application only has one value so the `()` aren't actually doing anything. I'll check it when I get back to work Monday.

Comment: Nope, it's the same error with the correct curly braces in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue in checkstyle: [github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/553](http://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/553)

As a workaround you can set *lineWrappingIndentation* property to zero:

```
<module name="Indentation">
    <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="0"/>
</module>
```

But in this case you will also need to remove extra indentations after line breaks, e.g.

```
return getCalculator().
    calculate(...);
```

instead of

```
return getCalculator(). 
        calculate(...);
```

Comment: I'm accepting this with the assumption that it is true. I don't work in this environment any longer, so I can't check it.